# Add a matrix in an empty matrix

Tags: r, matrix, addition

I would like to add a matrix of 3 columns in a specific position of an empty matrix, i.e.
this is my matrix "mat_data":

```
col1 col2 col3
 1    2    2           
 2    4    6            
 5    9    7            
 3    4    5
```

and my blank matrix "mat_blank":

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

and I would like to obtain:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 NA   NA   NA   NA   1    2    2   NA   NA
 NA   NA   NA   NA   2    4    6   NA   NA
 NA   NA   NA   NA   5    9    7   NA   NA
 NA   NA   NA   NA   3    4    5   NA   NA
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use their index like:

```
m[,5:7] <- m2
```

**Output**

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    1    2    2   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    2    4    6   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    5    9    7   NA   NA
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    3    4    5   NA   NA
```

**Data**

```
m <- matrix(NA, ncol = 9, nrow = 4)
m2 <- structure(c(1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 5L), .Dim = 4:3, .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("col1", "col2", "col3")))
```